# MP3 header missing from IP camera RTSP

Tags: c++, opencv, rtsp

I just want to show the IP camera video without sound, but this camera plays video with sound, and I get `[mp3 @ 0x107808800] Header missing` in the console. How do I play without sound? I'm using vstarcam-30s. Here is my code:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
     VideoCapture vcap; 
     Mat image; 

     string videoStreamAddress =
          "rtsp://[IPADDRESS]/profile2/media.smp";

      if (!vcap.open(videoStreamAddress)) { 
           cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << endl; 
           return -1; 
      } 

 for(;;) { 
      if(!vcap.read(image)) { 
           cout << "No frame" << endl; 
           waitKey(); 
         } 
          imshow("Output Window", image); 
          if(waitKey(1) >= 0) break; 
      } 
     return 0;
}
```